# JQuery: How to stop child onclick event while still triggering the parent onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how can I stop child onclick event while still triggering the parent onclick event. For example the following structure:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child1"></div>
   <div id="child2"></div>
   <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

if I click "child1" for example, the onclick event for "child1" will not be triggered, however, the onclick event for "parent" will still be triggered.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean every time it's clicked, or some special scenario?

Comment: why are you creating the children onclick events if you don't want them?

Comment: I actually want them but there exist some kind of situation in which I want to temporarily disable them.

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific about this... it can be as simple as setting a flag and let the child event handlers test that flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pass the `click` to the parent?

```
$('.child1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('#parent').trigger('click');
});
```

When you click .child1, it will prevent the default action, and then trigger the click for the parent of `child1` with an id of #parent.

Actually - probably ignore the above - as per the comment below it may cause bubbling. All you really need to do is use `e.stopPropagation();`.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/VnHGh/1/) showing how although the `child1` has a click function bound to it, it's being ignored, and so the parent click is only getting picked up.

Comment: The event will bubble up automatically though... you should not have to trigger the parent handler explicitly and in this case it might even trigger the handler twice.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I need! I remove the last command to trigger the parent like what Felix said and it works just fine!

Comment: Actually your example is incorrect. Two things: (a) `event.preventDefault()` only prevents the default action, but there is not default action associated with clicking on a div. (b) `event.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up, so in your fiddle, the parent event handler should not be called, but the child event handler. It does not though, because in the child event handler, you have an error: `e.stopPropagation()` should be `event.stopPropagation()`. So, your solution provides the desired result because you have an error in your code ;)

Comment: @NoOne: I cannot believe it works, because neither `event. preventDefault()` nor `event.stopPropagation()` is what you need here.  And in any case, this would be a permanent solution but as far as I understood, you want to disable the child event handler on runtime. If you'd provide more information, we could help you better.

Comment: Now your description does not fit to your fiddle anymore. The child event handler is executed, but not the parent one.

Comment: Why bind an event to the child at all?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is unbind the child's event handler.

```
$('#child1').unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution bin for above issue. please check demo link once.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7l

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    Child-1
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    Child-2
  </div>
  <div id="child3">
    Child-3
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#parent").click(function() {
        alert("Parent has been clicked too...!");
    });
    $("#child1").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("Child-1 has been clicked...!");
    });
    $("#child2").click(function() {
        alert("Child-2 has been clicked...!");
    });
    $("#child3").click(function() {
        alert("Child-3 has been clicked...!");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
  padding:5px;
  background:#a34477;
  width:140px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

#parent div{
  border:1px solid #2211a4;
  background:#a3a5dc;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:14px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:3px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7l

Answer (score 1):

do you mean:

```
$('#parent').on('click', function(e) { 
   if( e.target !== this ) {
       return;
   }
});
```

Comment: `.target` will always be that element you bind to, `.currentTarget` is the current event target.

Comment: whoaps! sorry, just got a little confused.